# Get the selected chart in Powerpoint using C# VSTO

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, interop

I'm trying to create a VSTO addon and I wanted the currently selected chart for my need. I wanted to change the data for the selected chart. I have a button in the ribbon bar. I wanted to change the title of the selected chart.

```
var selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;

// If selection is chart
// This is what I want 
selection.Title = "New Title";
```

Can anyone know that how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
var sel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;
                if(Sel.ShapeRange[1].Type == Office.MsoShapeType.msoChart && Sel.ShapeRange[1].Chart.HasTitle)
                {
                    Sel.ShapeRange[1].Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Test Title";
                }
```